# ssh remote commands hang on raspberry pi 3 but interactive works fine

Tags: ssh

I am trying to use ansible to configure a raspberry pi 3A+ with raspbian 10.  It is only copying files into a directory.  Each time I reinstall, it seems to work for a while, and then stop working.

When it stops working, the minimal problem is that `ssh raspberrypi` works but `ssh raspberrypi "echo HELLO"` hangs forever.  I took this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398252 and `ssh -t raspberrypi "echo HELLO"` works!

So I am going to try to make ansible do that.  However, I am still trying to figure out why it works for a minutes or hours on a new installation and then stops working.  I can run the remote command without `-t` on all my other devices.

Here is the output when it hangs:

```
ssh raspberrypi "echo HELLO"
...
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending command: echo HELLO
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

actually here is some of `-vvv`:

```
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: echo TEST
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

I have been trying to find out more about what `-t` does to figure out what could have changed.

My other raspberry pi where remote commands work even work like this `ssh raspberrypi -T "echo TEST"` and I think `-T` does the opposite of `-t`...

Also this is what is happening on the raspberry pi that hangs when you try to ssh commands to it:

```
$ ps aux | grep ssh
root       613  0.0  1.5  10728  5628 ?        Ss   06:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       673  0.0  1.6  12240  6316 ?        Ss   06:06   0:00 sshd: pi [priv]
pi         690  0.0  0.9  12240  3516 ?        S    06:06   0:00 sshd: pi
root       691  0.0  1.6  12240  6340 ?        Ss   06:06   0:00 sshd: pi [priv]
pi         697  0.0  0.9  12240  3528 ?        S    06:06   0:00 sshd: pi
root      1005  0.0  1.6  12240  6320 ?        Ss   06:17   0:00 sshd: pi [priv]
pi        1011  0.0  0.9  12240  3512 ?        S    06:17   0:00 sshd: pi
root      1081  2.8  1.6  12240  6308 ?        Ss   06:27   0:00 sshd: pi [priv]
pi        1087  0.2  0.9  12240  3508 ?        S    06:27   0:00 sshd: pi@pts/0
pi        1103  0.0  0.1   4784   504 pts/0    S+   06:28   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

even long after (one of those is my current connection, but I guess the rest are still trying to `echo TEST`)

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help to anybody, restarting my router fixed the problem:

```
debug1: Sending command: echo TEST
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 69
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
debug2: channel 0: written 69 to efd 6
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
TEST
```